# Lateral Android sliding menu

Tags: android

I am looking for lateral slidings menu for Android with backward compatibility to old API versions, but there are too many approaches on the net. I think it will be useful for everyone to know which ones are the best. Could you please post here the best approaches you have tried?

Comment: Why downvote? This question IS about programming, so it must not be the close reason even if there is no code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can (should) use [official Navigation Drawer](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html).

It is in support library v4 so you can use it with old API.

Here you can find an [example](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) from Android Team

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about that, even if looking for 'lateral sliding menu' on the net.